# Identify first tuple in a list

Tags: python-2.7, tuples

I am learning Python Tuples and I am stuck here. 
I have to count the no of single items till a tuple is reached. For eg in this input below, the output should be 4. This whole thing is a list btw.

I thought of adding an attempt but I don't really have a clue about this.

[4,3,7,1,(11,9,4,2,8),11,5,(8,9)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the list and count the numbers until you find a type tuple

Edited as suggested by AChampion see comment

```
xlist=[4,3,7,1,(11,9,4,2,8),11,5,(8,9)]

y=0
for x in xlist:
       if isinstance(x, tuple):
           break
       else:
           y=y+1
```

print(y)

```
print(y)
```

Output

```
4
```

Comment: No need to create a *dummy tuple* to compare to `tuple`, just use `tuple` it is more explicit and more readable, or alternatively `isinstance(x, tuple)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `type` Python function:

```
def first_tuple(mylist):
    for i,elt in enumerate(mylist):
        if type(elt) is tuple:
            return i
```